# External login using web api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:54581/api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true",
    type: Http_Get,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function () {}
```

after succesfull, array will look like this

```
 [  {
"Name": "Facebook",
"Url": "/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54581%2F&state=V8Tg_S0p2mnFNxJYMl2fEKrDWnTxg88lGS4PVnIGVFM1",
"State": "V8Tg_S0p2mnFNxJYMl2fEKrDWnTxg88lGS4PVnIGVFM1" }]
```

I will pass Url to my local host  "https://localhost:54581" + data[0].Url;

( window.location = "localhost:54581" + data[0].Url;)

after redirection I will get access token ,

url will look like this

```
localhost:54581/#access_token=_cZQsrmHJRm3M7_NHhYMU9uHlh9fH798KpnuqP6x5_e-XtYPba79NICgss0UfUrFA0jSQG11xGDh_STDBJ43v_3119oOtmRgsMiW1E6mxzgTNF7_3CThvnI-_e_Yz96UH0HDKsLJr3gEBlJc-Lx117Erk345IlZi3Mjc_m8r34s_Pk2XN3zOKQN7QrEKzN6h5mHbMQGm0xVKMcfLwl75bSz91CfM7fB4Rowui9NrhUH5uyfS60E7lFlxtyC4Jb5bY8EX4JgdWJewIWnVBHEEJnFriblPj5VEpC7GZuJVFdes5WwIfn_E0gLI9RPto7iNjtVQdOTVDOGfybPsPAHRkhNCK6o&token_type=bearer&expires_in=1209600&state=MNH52PGxHGTyqnX64XlF86-G97tAzpbLqD_pgjB-0ic1
```

but I want Access token in my html page ,

for example like this

index.html?Access_token="VQdOTVDOGfybPsPAHRkhNCK6"

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve but access token suggests it's some sort of authenticating value. Therefore, putting it in a query string is a security issue.